# Filtering out specific http api calls from open telemetry java agent instrumentation

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, open-telemetry, google-cloud-trace

I'm using the open telemetry java agent as documented [here](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/java/automatic/) to instrument a Java Spring Boot application and export the traces to Google Cloud Trace.

My command is :

```
java \
  -javaagent:/opentelemetry/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar \
  -Dotel.javaagent.extensions=/opentelemetry/exporter-auto-0.22.0-alpha.jar \
  -Dotel.traces.exporter=google_cloud_trace \
  -Dotel.metrics.exporter=none \
  -jar \
  /app.jar
```

It works.

However since I'm deploying my application under kubernetes with a liveness probe the agent also records traces for the `/actuator/health` endpoint.

I'd like to filter out these calls so that they are not recorded by the agent and sent to the collector.

The [agent configuration documentation](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/java/automatic/agent-config/#configuring-the-agent) doesn't seem to cover this use case.

**Is it possible to filter the traces by http calls but not yet documented ? Is it a planned feature ?**

Comment: Probably it would be useful to review the [agent’s feature requests](https://github.com/open-telemetry/oteps/issues) to see if this feature has been proposed, and if that is not the case, you may want to propose it.

Comment: I think this feature is not there ,but for workaround you can use RuleBasedRouting sampler and drop spans based on condition. 
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-contrib/blob/main/samplers/src/main/java/io/opentelemetry/contrib/sampler/RuleBasedRoutingSamplerBuilder.java